# Code is doubling the number of cache file instead of creating just one set in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, caching

I have a function which i need to cache in PHP. So i created one cache file for controller and other for view. In my cache folder both the cache files are generating but there is another set of cache files are generating along with it.

Here is My controller code:

```
function ajax_best_tag_call(){
    $postcat= $_POST['catId'];

    $ifLanguage = $this->session->userdata('lang');
    $BestTagcache_fileName = 'bestTagCall/BestTag_'.$ifLanguage.'_'.$_SESSION['cityAlias'].'_'.$postcat.'_controller';
    if(!$data = $this->cache->file->get($BestTagcache_fileName)){
        $data = array();
        $besttag_count      = $this->input->post('besttag_count');
        $besttag_neglected  = $this->input->post('besttag_neglected');
        $total_shown        = $besttag_count + $besttag_neglected;
        $excludeVenues      = $this->input->post('exclude_venues');
        $data['response']   = $this->best_tag_data($postcat,$besttag_count,$total_shown,$excludeVenues);

        $data['BesttagArr']     = $data['response'] ;
        $data['catId']      = $postcat;
        $data['exclude_venues'] = $data['response']['exclude_venues'];
        $data['total_best_tag'] = $data['response']['total_best_tag'];
        $this->cache->file->save($BestTagcache_fileName, $data,86400);//cache this page for 1 day
    }
    $ajaxresponse = $this->load->view("best_tag_ajax_data",$data,true);
    $content_ajax_send = array("html_detail"=>$ajaxresponse,"total_best_tag"=>$data['total_best_tag'],"total_shown"=>count($data['response']['mainarray']),"exclude_venues"=>$data['response']['exclude_venues'],"neglected"=>count($data['response']["neglected"]),"neglected_tags"=>$data['response']["neglected"]);

    echo json_encode($content_ajax_send);
}
```

and here is the view code:

```
<?php
$ifLanguage = $this->session->userdata('lang');
$BestTagcache_file = 'bestTagCall/BestTag_'.$ifLanguage.'_'.$_SESSION['cityAlias'].'_'.$catId.'_view';
if(!$html_detail = $this->cache->file->get($BestTagcache_file)){
$html_detail = '';
foreach($BesttagArr['mainarray'] as $value)
{
    $best_tag_name = $value[3];
    $UrlArr = explode("/",$value[1]);
    $lastUrlText = end($UrlArr); unset($UrlArr[count($UrlArr)-1]);
    $urlFinal = implode("/",$UrlArr)."/".$lastUrlText;
    $bestUrl = $urlFinal;

    $html_detail .='<div class="col-lg-4 besttags">
    <div class="img_box addtransform">
        <a href="'.$bestUrl.'">
          <img class="four_by_three" src="'.$value[0].'">
          <div class="img_Title" id="img_Titles">
              <div class="c_title"></div>
              <div class="c_subtitle">'.ucwords(traslate_word($best_tag_name)).'</div>
          </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>';
}
$this->cache->file->save($BestTagcache_file, $html_detail,86400);//cache this page for 1 day
 }
  echo $html_detail;
 ?>
```

and here is the screen shot of the files which are generated

[image]

As you can see first two files are exactly what i did in the code but last two is something which are not intended. first two has information but second two is not giving full information. I don't understand how last two files are generating. Please help.

Comment: what if we clean the cache before generating it?

Comment: same result.. no luck!! i tried to delete the last two file but next time it generated again.

Comment: with these? `$this->cache->clean();` or `ob_flush()` - `ob_start()`

Comment: Looks like you have duplicated request, and the second one without `catId` in request POST payload. Try to add `if (empty($_POST['catId'])) return;` as a first line in your controller method, and see, if it helps.

Comment: The empty condition helps but it would be a patch and still not sure from where the empty catId is coming? I checked everything, Request is going once, function is being called once and there is no duplicate request. so where is the catId come empty from?

Comment: From that point I`ll start checking server access logs for given URL (or trying to send backtrace to log or email on each controller method call, but logs first).

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the code to save to the cache on the view. I would recommend you only do that in your controller, seeing that the routing will call you controller before the view is displayed.

So when your route is called a cached file is created and then again when your view is eventually displayed.